# Host a ASP.net MVC Website and access it externally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, localhost, web-hosting

I am pretty new to hosting and stuff like that. I want to know how can we host a ASP.net MVC application within our own IIS and access it from another device over the internet.

What I did:
1)Enabled IIS Manager in my computer.
2)Opened IIS Manager and created a new website (published my application into a folder and linked it) and set the bindings like a new domain name, gave my own IP address and a different port number other than 80.
3) Edited my host file to direct the domain name to my local IIS

After doing all the above, I tried accessing the website from Chrome(local machine) using domain name, all worked fine.

Then I proceeded to access the site from my own mobile over the internet, and it was unsuccessful. Even after using the IpAdress:Port format, it was unsuccessful. I looked into a lot of tutorials but I couldn't get anything related to my issue. Can you please help? Is it impossible to do this? Basically I want my machine to act as a web server.

Comment: is your hosting IP is dedicated IP? If yes then you could find it over internet, if no then (in case of shared IP) you could access your application from local network (ex: WiFi).

Comment: No my IP is the one that we get after typing ipconfig command in the command prompt, so I guess that makes it a shared IP.